# Mailing package at Heathrow during layover

Tags: layovers, lhr, mail

I am flying Phoenix USA to Stockholm Sweden via Heathrow/LHR. I'll have ~4 hour layover (connecting flights both Finnair). My carry on will be a package I want to mail to Germany (2 vintage framed pictures). Is it feasible/possible to do this at LHR? How easy/difficult to do?

Comment: Which Terminal do you arrive into? There is a Post Office landside in Terminal 3 https://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/terminal-facilities-and-services/postal-services

Comment: I removed the part about rechecking bags because it's unrelated to your main question about mail. You can post it as a separate question if you like but I'm sure it's already been answered on the site so please search first.

Comment: Any form of customs declaration should be sent with the package. After Brexit, the package should be sent from Sweden (i. e. from within the customs union).

Answer (score 3):

If you have a 4 hour layover, you may need to pass through immigration and leave the terminal but that’s easily doable in 4 hours.

Here are the Post Office details at Heathrow:

> The airport Post Office is on the first floor of Terminal 3 departures, in the public area before security ( it's near the security control entrance).
>
> Opening hours: Monday to Saturday 09:00 - 17:30, Sunday 09:00 - 13:00.
>   Telephone: +44 (0)20 8897 3463

([Heathrow Website](https://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/terminal-facilities-and-services/postal-services))

Finnair flights leave from Terminal 3 anyway:

> Finnair flights from Heathrow Airport will leave from Terminal 3, Zone G.

([Finnair Website](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwiWz73Xl8PkAhXiQkEAHY8OB-QQFjACegQIDBAF&url=https%3A%2F%2Fflights.finnair.com%2Fen-gb%2Fflights-from-london&usg=AOvVaw14WbVnJShcP_1e3aBme4bM))

Considering it is the same terminal you should have plenty of time. All you need to do is exit the airport through immigration. The report from [July](https://www.heathrow.com/file_source/Company/Static/PDF/Companynewsandinformation/Border_Force_Performance_Jul19.pdf) states an average of 45 minutes for NON EAA Immigration, say it takes an hour to get to the post office, you will still have at least 2 and a half hours in the case of delays before your flight.

Comment: Note you'd need to pass security anyways on transfer so the time delta really is just immigration.